# How to make the scroll on Mac not accelerate?

Tags: mac, mouse, scrolling

On Windows, one click of the mouse wheel is ~3 lines in the editor. 2 clicks is ~6 lines, 3 clicks is ~9 lines, and so on.

On the Mac mini 2018 (OS X 10.15.7) I am currently forced to work with, one click of the mouse wheel is ~3 pixels, 2 clicks is ~6 lines and 3 clicks is ~9 pages, which is good if you need to scroll quickly down to an EULA Accept button, but really really bad if you have to actually read long texts.

Is this a bug in OS X w.r.t to 3rd party mouses that actually have a (clicking) scroll wheel, or just a wrong setting? How can I get my mouse wheel to behave similar on Mac mini as on Windows?

Comment: You can't get that exact 3-lines, it just doesn't work that way, but if your acceleration is going from 6 lines to 9 pages, something is seriously wrong with your settings. What mouse do you have & does it come with its own drivers, e.g. Logitech?

Comment: @Tetsujin The model is "Cherry M5400" and I don't think there was a driver disk delivered with it. I just want the acceleration to stop, I'm okay if it's 4 lines or 6 lines, as long as it's a sane fixed amount of scroll per click.

Comment: You might need something like [USB Overdrive](https://www.usboverdrive.com) or [SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/) if it has really whacky acceleration.

Comment: The same mouse is working totally fine on Windows with default drivers. The Apple mouse is even worse - it has acceleration, it is worse than my $100 mobile phone at recognizing user input, and it doesn't have any user feedback.

Comment: I just checked, 3 clicks of the mouse wheel is 180 to 230 lines in my editor, with 40 lines fitting on the screen. It's not even the same on each scroll, maybe depends on how quickly you scroll.

Comment: It does depend on how fast you scroll, but your acceleration is seriously out of whack. Mac scrolling should be considerably more subtle than Windows, if you scroll slowly you can scroll in partial lines, pretty much pixel by pixel, one 'click' is one line but even that moves slowly & can be stopped at any point between. Then the faster you scroll, the more acceleration is pushed into it. Did you actually check either of those apps to see what your acceleration is set to & how to adjust it?

Comment: I have to yet get green light from IT to install any of these apps.